# Date output as command-line argument

Tags: bash

I'd like to count syslog entries matching a pattern in the last 5 minutes.

I can hardcode a time and get the expected output:

```
$ awk '$3>"16:20:00"' /var/log/syslog | grep "UFW BLOCK" | wc -l
1502
```

The desired time can be constructed with:

```
$ date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%H:%M:%S'
16:00:00
```

**How can I join these in a one-liner?**

I tried setting an environment variable, but it returns the entire log. I can't see my error.

```
$ logdate=`date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%H:%M:%S'` && awk '$3>"$logdate"' /var/log/syslog | grep "UFW BLOCK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
awk -v dt="$(date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%H:%M:%S')" '$3>dt && /UFW BLOCK/' /var/log/syslog
```

Note how you can avoid last `grep` by using awk to do the search pattern as well.

Comment: Thank you, the -v allows assigning a variable for use in the program text! It's right there in the man page. +2 for pattern matching in the awk expression

Answer (score 1):

Your awk command is single-quoted, which disables the shell's string interpolation. An easy way to check yourself on this type of error is to change `awk` to `echo` and see what it says (`$3>"$logdate"`). If you used double-quotes and escaped the characters appropriately (`"\$3>\"$logdate\""`, then you would be passing to `awk` that argument that you intended.

```
$ logdate=`date --date='5 minutes ago' '+%H:%M:%S'` && awk "\$3>\"$logdate\"" /var/log/syslog | grep "UFW BLOCK"
```

Comment: Thanks for signing up to show me this Scott, welcome to SO!

Comment: Using shell variables like that in awk is a recipe for disaster, though, and you should always use `awk -v var=value` instead.